# Как исправить ошибку при выполнении функции mysqli_real_connect()?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, localhost

Всем привет!
У меня Mac OS и MAMP Pro, пытаюсь поднять один сайт на вордпрессе у себя на локалке, но застопорился на одной вещи. Во время настроек выполняется один скрипт на php, к-й выдает ошибку на месте использования функции mysqli_real_connect() :

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

Погуглил, встретил ответ на этот вопрос, то что необходимо в файле config.inc.php поменять хост с `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'` на `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'`, но это не сработало.

Подскажите, куда копать, что посмотреть, что поэкспериментировать, чтобы выявить и исправить неполадку? И да, я чайник.

Кстати, этот сайт у меня уже поднят на винде, может там я смогу найти подсказку ?

Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: Не надо ломать WordPress, используйте его класс для работы с базой:  https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb

Comment: А ещё лучше - функции WordPress, которые есть на все случаи жизни

Comment: к сожалению, такой возможности нет, скрипт писал не я, необходимо просто его запустить без ошибок, но не выходит ...